# How can I remove shadows from a descriptive diagram?

Tags: smartdiagram

I have included one descriptive diagram to my `beamer` slides, and while it is perfect for my needs, I would like to remove the shadows it has by default. I have tried with tikz and adding an additional setting as follows:

```
\tikzset{no shadows/.code=\let\tikz@preactions\pgfutil@empty}

        \smartdiagramset{set color list={orange, blue,
            yellow,pink,lime},
        uniform connection color=true,
        description text width=10cm,
        module minimum height=0.5cm,
        descriptive items y sep=1.3,
        description title width=1cm,
        additions={
            additional item shadow=no shadows
            }
        }
```

but it is not working. Any advice?

Comment: Yes. Please post a *complete* minimal document and not just snippets.

Comment: As a workaround you can use `\tikzset{every shadow/.style={fill=none,shadow xshift=0pt,shadow yshift=0pt}}`.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the code of `smartdiagram`, `drop shadow`s seem to be hard-coded to appear. You can use, as a workaround,

```
\tikzset{every shadow/.style={fill=none,shadow xshift=0pt,shadow yshift=0pt}}
```

or

```
\tikzset{every shadow/.style={fill=none,shadow scale=0}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\tikzset{
  every shadow/.style={
    fill=none,
    shadow xshift=0pt,
    shadow yshift=0pt}
}
\smartdiagramset{
  set color list={orange, blue,yellow,pink,lime},
  uniform connection color=true,
  description text width=10cm,
  module minimum height=0.5cm,
  descriptive items y sep=1.3,
  description title width=1cm,
}
\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{PGF,Ti\textit{k}Z,Smartdiagram}{}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]